Can only load Google webpages
I ran the below commands from the SurfShark wed site:
curl -f https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh --output surfshark-install.sh #gets the installation script
cat surfshark-install.sh #shows script's content
sh surfshark-install.sh #installs surfshark

I was unable to connect to any VPN listed, so I uninstalled it using the below commands given to me by SurfShark:
sudo apt purge surfshark # deletes surfshark GUI and its dependencies
sudo apt purge surfshark-vpn # deletes CLI dependencies, in case the CLI tool is installed
sudo apt purge surfshark-release # deletes our repository package

I received the following error messages:
vance@vance-VP4650:~$ sudo apt purge surfshark
[sudo] password for vance:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
surfshark*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
After this operation, 286 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 241791 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing surfshark (3.0.5-4575) ...
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-surfshark-and-globally-managed-devices.conf': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
(Reading database ... 241485 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for surfshark (3.0.5-4575) ...
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-surfshark-and-globally-managed-devices.conf': No such file or directory
vance@vance-VP4650:~$ sudo apt purge surfshark-vpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'surfshark-vpn' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
vance@vance-VP4650:~$ sudo apt purge surfshark-release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'surfshark-release' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

Now I can only access Google pages. Any other website will not load. I have tried several browsers with the same results
SurfShark has been little help and has not refunded my money, so beware.

The instruction should be curl -O https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh Surfshark's web page asks you to use the option -f. This is the wrong option for saving the file. source

@graham I pasted the curl -f https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh --output surfshark-install.sh command from the question into a Ubuntu 24.04.1 shell, and the file was downloaded and saved as surfshark-install.sh (albeit no execute permission). The script creates a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/surfshark.list file and then attempts to install the surfshark package. From the question I think what happened is that the surfshark package failed to add a VPN, but left the networking broken when the package was un-installed. Not sure how best to debug what happened.

maybe 22.04 (the OPs version) works differently?
